# Compile LESS to multiple CSS files, based on variable value

Tags: css, gruntjs, less

Having a single variable that specifies a color within a `variables.less` file (e.g. `@themeColor: #B30F55;`), and a `.json` file that constitutes a list of entities, where each key is an entity ID and the value of the key is that entity's color (e.g. `'8ab834f32' : '#B30F55', '3cc734f31' : '#99981F'`), how could I run a Grunt task that outputs as many independent CSS files as there are entities in the json, after substituting the variable value?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a different task for each color. grunt-contrib-less supports the Modifyvars option:

> modifyVars
>
> Type: Object Default: none
>
> Overrides global variables. Equivalent to --modify-vars='VAR=VALUE'
>   option in less.

You can set `modifyVars: themeColor={yourcolor}` for each task

> .json file that constitutes a list of entities

See: [Grunt - read json object from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934315/grunt-read-json-object-from-file)

An other example can be found at [Dynamic Build Processes with Grunt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832800/dynamic-build-processes-with-grunt-js/13862662)

**example**

colors.json:

```
{
"colors" : [
{"color" : "#B30F55", "name" : "8ab834f32"},
{"color" : "#99981F", "name" : "3cc734f31"}
]
}
```

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  'use strict';
grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
var allTaskArray = [];
var colors = grunt.file.readJSON('colors.json').colors;
var tasks = {};   
for (var color in colors) {
var dest =  'dist/css/' + [colors[color].name] + '.css';
tasks[colors[color].name] = {options: {
          strictMath: true,
          outputSourceFiles: true,
          modifyVars: {}
        },files:{} };
tasks[colors[color].name]['files'][dest] = 'less/main.less';       
tasks[colors[color].name]['options']['modifyVars']['color'] = colors[color].color;
allTaskArray.push('less:' + colors[color].name);
}   
grunt.config('less',tasks);
grunt.registerTask( 'default', allTaskArray );
};
```

less/main.less:

```
@color: red;
p{
color: @color;
}
```

than run `grunt`:

> Running "less:8ab834f32" (less) task File dist/css/8ab834f32.css
>   created: 24 B → 24 B
>
> Running "less:3cc734f31" (less) task File dist/css/3cc734f31.css
>   created: 24 B → 24 B
>
> Done, without errors.

cat dist/css/3cc734f31.css:

```
p {
  color: #99981f;
}
```